# Desarrollo de un avatar humano 3D

Tags: javascript, 3d

Gracias por su ayuda.

Necesito programar un avatar con figura humana en 3D, como asistente de una aplicación, la idea es que pueda animarlo con javascript para que le hable al usuario, camine, le despliegue opciones al usuario.

Alguien tiene idea de cómo lo puedo hacer?

No he iniciado a trabajarlo por que estoy revisando cual es la mejor forma.

Gracias,

Comment: Hola Jorge, la mejor forma de preguntar en [es.so] es siguiendo esta guía __"[ask]"__ y agregando, siempre que sea posible un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno en cuanto al *avatar* se refiere, dices que debe ser *3D* puedes hacer uso de una *biblioteca* de Js que se llama **Three.js**.
Ésta biblioteca te puede servir para eso ya que de cierta manera puedes crear tu gráfico en 3D además cuenta con otras opciones para que tu modelado quede listo.

También existe otra que se llama **Pre3D**, ésta cuenta con documentación seguida de un ejemplo sencillo para no perderse.
**Babylon.js** también es buena pero está orientada mas a juegos interactivos, y empleas *Javascript* y *HTML5*.
Espero te pueda servir :)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta!